# AngularJS - Allowing location change based on route meta-data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Problem Statement:**
Based on whether a user is logged-in and a certain route is secure or not - allow the location change. So, **secure** meta-data true/false is declared against the route.

```
.when('/myapp', {
                templateUrl : function($node, tattrs) {
                      return "resources/html/home.html";
                },
                controller  : 'mainController',
                secure: false
            })

    .when('/myapp/editorder/:orderId', {
                templateUrl : 'resources/html/order.html',
                controller  : 'orderController',
                secure: true
            })
```

.....
.....

```
.run(function ($rootScope, $location, $route) {

        $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart",function(event, next, current){

            var nextPath = $location.path();
            nextRoute = $route.routes[nextPath];

            if( !$rootScope.MyUserService.isLoggedIn && nextRoute.secure ){
                //prevent location change.
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        })
    })
```

**Question:**
If a route has a param in template url eg: /myapp/editorder/:orderId  (orderId in this example), nextRoute becomes undefined, so i am unable to access **nextRoute.secure**

Everything works fine if there is no param in route
Any ideas? Or alternative ways to implement this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant but I am not sure if there is another way to achieve ... though this will do it:

```
var getRouteByPath = function(path){
    var matchedRoute;
    angular.forEach($route.routes, function(route, key){
        if (!matchedRoute) {
            if (key.indexOf(path) === 0) {
                matchedRoute = route;
            }
        }
    });
    return matchedRoute;
}
```

Nevertheless you might get ambiguous results with the above snippet ... but I think the idea behind this approach is clear ;)